# Unable to load boot strap modal using jquery post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have one main jsp page, here I have 6 inputs, on click of each input I'm having a jquery onclickfunction and here I'm using jquery post method to load a jsp page in which I'm calling db function to get data and then show this as boot strap modal.

The code is written as shown:

```
$("#simplesearchporginputid").click(function (event) {
    try {
        //if($("#autosearchlist1").attr("for")== "purchaseorg")
        //{
        //}else
        //{
        //}
        $.post("AutoSearchPurchOrgList.jsp", {}, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            // $("#autosearchlist1").attr("for","purchaseorg"); 
            $("#autosearchlist1").html(data);
            $('#PurhcaseOrgModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        document.getElementById("DisplayErrorMessage").innerHTML = err.message;
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

Here autosearch list is a div id in main tag, where I'm loading the data from `autosearchpurchorglist.jsp` and in this loaded data I have a boot strap modal with id as PurchaseOrgModal and then I'm using `$('#PurchaseOrgModal').modal('show');`

But it is not working, instead the screen is loaded with transparent blackish empty screen where I'm able to see inputs and other things in main jsp but unable to click them etc... please help me to solve the issue..

and HTML modal is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="*******.jco.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.*****.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Purchase Org Autosearch List</title>
 <script>


 </script>
</head>
 <body>

  <!-- Auto search feature -->
        <%

        GBSServletRequest.g_obj_Request = request;
        GBSServletRequest.g_obj_Respons = response;
        SmartSearch smartSearchObject = new SmartSearch();
        Log logobject = new Log();

        %>

        <div class="modal fade" id="PurhcaseOrgModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><img src="IMG/*******" /></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select <span id="which_country"></span> Purch Org #</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header-search">
         <label>Enter Key Word</label> <input type="text" placeholder="" title="" value="" class="dd_search_country">
      </div>
      <%

      JCO.Table purchaserOrgIdTable = smartSearchObject.getlistofPurchaseorgID();
      %>
      <div class="modal-body countylist_tcode">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding=20 cellspacing=0  border=0 class="countrylist country">
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>      
        <% 
         try
         {
             purchaserOrgIdTable.setRow(0);

             do{ 
              String purch_org_desc = (String) purchaserOrgIdTable.getString(IConstants.******);
              String purch_org_key = (String)purchaserOrgIdTable.getString(IConstants.*******);
              String purch_org_key_desc = (String)purchaserOrgIdTable.getString(IConstants.**************);
       %>

             <tr>
             <%String keyvalue = purch_org_key ; %>
              <td 
              data-search_country="<%=purch_org_desc %>" 
              data-search_country_code="<%=purch_org_key%>" 
              class="countryli">
              <input type="radio" 
              value="<%=purch_org_key %>" 
              data-search_country="<%=purch_org_desc %>" 
              data-search_country_code="<%=purch_org_key%>" 
              class="country_radio_btn country_check_btn" name="country"> 
              <span class="td">
              <%=purch_org_key_desc %>
              </span>
              </td>
              <%purchaserOrgIdTable.nextRow(); %>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>

              <td 
              data-search_country="<%=purch_org_desc%>" 
              data-search_country_code="<%=purch_org_key%>">
              <input type="radio" 
              value="<%= purch_org_key%>" 
              data-search_country="<%= purch_org_desc %>" 
              data-search_country_code="<%= purch_org_key%>" 
              class="country_radio_btn country_check_btn" 
              name="country"> 
              <span class="country_name">
              <%=purch_org_key_desc %>
              </span>

              </tr>
               <%
            }while(purchaserOrgIdTable.nextRow());
          }catch(Exception e)
             {

             }
        %>
          </table> 

       <div class="nomatch"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="BookMarkmodal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_checked_val" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It;s more like HTML issue, sound like modal overlay is causing the problem can you post the modal HTML

Comment: hi shehary , have added above modal code